# How to exclude all files under a directory in lint using angular CLI?

Tags: angular, angular-cli, lint

We can exclude node_modules in this way.

```
  "lint": [
        {
          "project": "src/main/webapp/app/file.json",
          "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
        }
    ]
```

But how to exclude all files under a directory?

I tried below way. It is not working

```
"exclude": [
 "**/*whatever.pipe.ts", 
 "**/*whatever_else.component.ts"
]
```

So this is my current path for the directory `"src/main/assets/js/ngx-typeahead"`

I have to exclude all the files under this directory from linting.

How can i achieve that?

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

You can do that by modifying your `lint` line inside `tsconfig.json`:

```
"lint": [
    {
        "exclude": [
            "src/main/assets/js/ngx-typeahead/**/*.ts", 
        ]
    }
]
```

This `PATH/**/*.ts` means all files under this path and any subdirectory inside with the extension `.ts`

And I believe `"src/main/assets/js/ngx-typeahead/*` will exclude all files under this path

**Edit:**
Another option is to use `tslint.json`:

```
{
    "extends": "tslint:recommended",
    ......
    "linterOptions": { 
        "exclude": [
            "src/main/assets/js/ngx-typeahead/**/*.ts", 
        ]
    }
}
```

For more: https://palantir.github.io/tslint/usage/configuration/

**Edit 2:** 
I found [this issue link](https://github.com/mgechev/codelyzer/issues/268#issuecomment-298395031) for angular-cli specific linting, by providing what exactly you want to lint instead of linting the project with excludes!

inside `.angular-cli.json` provide `lint` option:

```
"lint": [{
      "files": "src/**/*.ts",
      "project": "src/tsconfig.app.json"
    },
    {
      "files": "src/**/*.ts",
      "project": "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
    },
    {
      "files": "src/**/*.ts",
      "project": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json"
    }
]
```

Comment: Hey thanks for answering. I dont know why above solution is  not working for me

Comment: @al-mothafar is "exclude" used to completely exclude the files from the project? The OP is asking to exclude them only from lint.

Comment: @MarcoAltieri where I mention that I exclude files from the project?  the exclude line logically is inside `tsconfig.json` file inside `"lint": [ ..... ]` so it will configure tslint, not the project.

Comment: @al-mothafar I think your answer needs to be complete. If you are suggesting to add the exclude in the lint section, you should at least mention it.

Comment: @MarcoAltieri I have editied my answer, hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Finally this works for me

```
"lint": [
    {
      "project": "src/main/webapp/app/tsconfig.app.json",
      "exclude": ["**/node_modules/**", "**/src/main/assets/js/ngx-typeahead**"]
    }
```