# Exclude the reference library project folder in LINT with angular 10

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, lint, angular10

I am trying to exclude the reference library project files while running the command `npm run lint`, but it is not working for me.

In the main application, I have added these code in the angular.json

**Angular.json**

```
 "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "projects/pts-ngx/core/tsconfig.lib.json",
              "projects/pts-ngx/core/tsconfig.spec.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**",
              "**/projects/ors-testtaker-bff/**"
            ]
          }
        }
```

I have the below file structure and trying to exclude the files inside API and MODEL folder

[image]

Followed the instruction from below

[How to exclude all files under a directory in lint using angular CLI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48884789/how-to-exclude-all-files-under-a-directory-in-lint-using-angular-cli)

Answer (score 0):

This help me

From tslint v5.8.0 you can now ignore files from your tslint.json file. Just add this to your toplevel tslint.json file:

```
     "linterOptions": {
    "exclude": ["projects/ors-testtaker-bff/api/**/*","projects/ors-testtaker-bff/model/**/*"]
}
```